# Progressbar below Toolbar in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a layout XMl like this :

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <RelativeLayout/>
            <Toolbar/>
        </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </AppBarLayout>
    <RecyclerView/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want to add a horizontal progressbar just below the toolbar and above the recycler view to indicate data loading for recycler view items.

With a relative layout, I could have simply provided a android:layout_below property for progressbar below action bar. But being new to Coordinator Layout and Toolbar, I am unable to get the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide `ProgressBar` with `Toolbar` wrap `Toolbar` inside `LinearLayout` and put `ProgressBar` as a first child of this `LinearLayout`. Assign

```
orientation="vertical"
```

If you would like `ProgressBar` to be always visible, then wrap `RecyclerView` inside `LinearLayout` and put `ProgressBar` as a first child. Set the orientation. Remember to add

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

as a paramter of `LinearLayout` (It must pass the scrolling to the child)

Answer (score 3):

Place the ProgressBar as a direct child of the CoordinatorLayout.

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <ImageView/>
            <Toolbar/>
        </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </AppBarLayout>
    <NestedScrollView>
    </NestedScrollView>
    <ProgressBar/>
    <BottomAppBar/>
    <FloatingActionButton/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

For the ProgressBar, use layout_anchor and anchor it the AppBarLayout (equal to AppBarLayout id). Set the layout_anchorGravity to bottom.

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="@{viewModel.loading ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appBarLayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom" />
```

I'm attaching the code and the preview screenshot.
[image: Horizontal Progress Bar showing properly]

Answer (score 1):

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <RelativeLayout/>
            <Toolbar/>
        </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </AppBarLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
      <ProgressBar>
      <RecyclerView/>
    </LinearLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

The above should work for what you want. Make sure the orientation on the linear layout is vertical. The only caveat is that if your recycler view is large you may need to wrap the linear layout in a nest scroll view assuming you want the progress bar to scroll as well.